# Regarding calculating the length of arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have this int array,

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

When I calculate the length of the array using,

```
int length = arr.length;
```

this gave me `5`. But, when I use the below line i.e

```
int last = arr[arr.length - 1];
```

it still gave me `5` instead of `4`, though we are deducting it by `1`.

Why does the array behave like this?

Comment: the value of that element is five, it's index is four.

Answer (score 1):

The array in Java is **zero-based**.

```java
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

int length = arr.length;            // 5 (total items, from index 0 - 4)
int firstItem = arr[0];             // 1 
int lastItem = arr[arr.length - 1]; // 5
```